# Azure startup script is not executed

Tags: azure, server, azure-web-app-service, startup, azure-deployment

I've learned [how to deploy .sh scripts to Azure with Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-zip?tabs=cli#deploy-individual-files). But it seems like I have  no clear understanding of how they work.

I'm creating the script that simply unarchives a .tgz archive in a current directory of Azure Web App, and then just deletes it. Quite simple:

```
New-Item ./startup.sh
Set-Content ./startup.sh '#!/bin/sh'
Add-Content ./startup.sh 'tar zxvf archive.tgz; rm-rf ./archive.tgz'
```

And then I deploy the script like this:

```
az webapp deploy --resource-group Group 
                 --name Name
                 --src-path ./startup.sh 
                 --target-path /home/site/wwwroot/startup.sh
                 --type=startup
```

Supposedly, it should appear in `/home/site/wwwroot/`, but for some reason it never does. No matter how I try. I thought it just gets executed and then deleted automatically (since I specified it as a `startup` script), but the archive is there, not unarchived at all.

My stack is .NET Core.

What am I doing wrong, and what's the right way to do what I need to do? Thank you.

Comment: please provide the command that you create your app service, my point is what kind of app service are you creating, more or less so when I want to help you to reproduce the creation of the app service before deploying anything. to ensure my answer is authetic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if it makes sense, but I think the problem might be that you're using the `target-path` parameter while you should be using `path` instead.

From the [documentation you cited](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-zip?tabs=cli#deploy-individual-files), when describing the Azure CLI functionality, they state:

> The CLI command uses the Kudu publish API to deploy the package and can be
> fully customized.

The [Kudu publish API reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-zip?tabs=cli#kudu-publish-api-reference) indicates, when describing the different values for type and especially `startup`:

> `type=startup`: Deploy a script that App Service automatically uses as the
> startup script for your app. By default, the script is deployed to
> `D:\home\site\scripts\<name-of-source>` for Windows and
> `home/site/wwwroot/startup.sh` for Linux. The target path can be specified
> with `path`.

Note the use of `path`:

> The absolute path to deploy the artifact to. For example,
> "/home/site/deployments/tools/driver.jar", "/home/site/scripts/helper.sh".

I never tested it, I am aware that the option is not described when taking about the [`az webapp deploy` command itself](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp?view=azure-cli-latest#az-webapp-deploy), and it may be just an error in the documentation, but it may work:

```
az webapp deploy --resource-group Group 
                 --name Name
                 --src-path ./startup.sh 
                 --path /home/site/wwwroot/startup.sh
                 --type=startup
```

Note that the path you are providing is the default one; as a consequence, you could safely delete it if required:

```
az webapp deploy --resource-group Group 
                 --name Name
                 --src-path ./startup.sh
                 --type=startup
```

Finally, try including some debug or `echo` commands in your script: perhaps the problem can be motivated for any permissions issue and having some traces in the logs could be helpful as well.

Comment: I'm on a vacation now :D but I'll check if this works asap, and accept the answer if it works.

Comment: That is fine @AleksandrNovik.  Enjoy your holidays!!

Comment: I do not know why but for me path parameter is not working. it says 
unrecognized arguments: --path